# Hot topics? Cool questions? thermal, thermal-control, heat, heat-flow, cooling, sub-cooled, liquid-cooled tags; is there room for some consolidation?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tagging

- [thermal](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thermal): **96** questions

> How heat affects spacecraft and space missions, or materials and methods to deal with heat.

- [thermal-control](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thermal-control): **67** questions

> Questions about heat management in spacecraft

- [heat](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heat): **61** questions:

> Questions about issues related to heat and temperature, and situations where heat (too much or too little) is the primary issue. Examples include heat management in spacecraft and heat used for power generation using the flow of thermal energy from a source to a sink.

- [heat-flow](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heat-flow): **10** questions

> ...has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?

- [cooling](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cooling): **25** questions

> ...has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?

- [sub-cooled](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sub-cooled): **15** questions

> Cooling liquid propellants well below their boiling point - increases density and other benefits.

- [liquid-cooled](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/liquid-cooled): **7** questions

> ...has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?

- Some of these need usage guidance
- Some of these may be too specific or overlap too much with other tags

**Question:** Is there room for some tag consolidation here?

Answer (score 3):

Seems like [thermal](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thermal) should be merged and synonymized with [heat](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heat), and [cooling](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cooling) should be merged and synonymized with [thermal-control](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thermal-control).

I'm less certain on the others. More than a few users found them useful, so they should probably stay as is.

Comment: hopefully this answer will receive a few more UP VOTES to indicate community approval, or of course down votes and indications of disapproval. Anything except nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Ugh, it's a mess.

Looks like there are a few basic topics covered by these:

- rocket engine cooling
- propellant densification via "sub-cooling"
- steady-state spacecraft and habitat thermal management
- atmospheric heating on ascent and reentry

I feel like `thermal`, `thermal-control`, `heat`, and `heat-flow` could all be merged into `thermal-control`, but the usage is pretty inconsistent across those topics.

Comment: This is a good point. I'm not sure I'd merge [tag:heat] into [tag:thermal-control] though. It seems like [tag:heat] has some pretty good reasons to stand on its own, I think.

Comment: Ooof, there are even a couple more topics now that I think about it.